# Set iFrame checkbox that is hidden from the user

Tags: javascript

I have a web page that consists of a checkbox (parent) and on this same web page, I also have a iframe that is sourced from another page that displays a number of records, which also has a checkbox (children) against each record. If I tick the parent checkbox and assume the iframe is hidden from the user (have a feature to show/hide iframe), can I set all children checkboxs within this hidden iframe or does the iframe need to be rendered?

I am hoping that this can be achieved without rendering the iframe contents.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is possible; regardless of the iframe's display state, it is still part of the DOM. (I assume you're hiding it using CSS "visibility:hidden" or -- more likely -- "display:none".)

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function updateFrameCheck(childName, status)
{
  var x = document.getElementById("frameThing");
  var y = x.contentDocument.getElementById("formIdFromIframe");
  y.elements[childName].checked = status;
}
</script>
</head>
<body>

<iframe src="otherpage.htm" id="frameThing"></iframe>

<input type="checkbox" onclick="updateFrameCheck(this.name, this.checked)" name="childName" />

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I'm going to guess the iframe isn't just hidden because he said 'or does it need to be rendered', but the wording is iffy.

Comment: Based on the way it is working, my iframe is not actually rendered until the user actually expands as I have just tested it. But when I actually press on the expand button to render the iframe, my requried functionlaity works. Is there anyway I can get around this?

Comment: "not actually rendered" -- meaning, you're dynamically adding it into the DOM upon the user expanding it? (That would explain the not-working aspect.) Or it's drawn to the page but hidden with CSS? (That's what you want, which should allow functionality while hidden.)

Answer (score 0):

It does not matter if the Iframe is shown to the user or not. Even if you set css style as 'display: none' you can still programatically interact with the contents of the iframe.

You can set all the checkboxes and display to the user when ready.